# order of a polynomial at a prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $R$ is a unique factorization domain, and that $k$ is its field of fractions. For a prime element $p\in{R}$, we define the $\it{order}$ of $p$ at ${a/b}\in{R}$, denoted by ${{\nu}_p}(a/b)$, as follows. By unique factorization, we can write $${\frac{a}{b}}={{\epsilon}{\prod}_{p:{\rm{prime}}}p^{n_p}}$$ where $n_p$ is an integer in a unique way. We define ${{\nu}_p}(a/b)=n_p$, and for a polynomial $$f(X)={{\sum}^m_{i=0}}{a_i}X^{i}\in{k[X]},$$ the order of $p$ at $f$, denoted by ${{\nu}_p}(f)$ to be $${{\nu}_p}(f)=min_{0\leq{i}\leq{m}}({{\nu}_p}(a_i)).$$
I am trying to prove that $${{\nu}_p}(fg)={{\nu}_p}(f)+{{\nu}_p}(g).$$ The proof is straightforward if $f$, and $g$ are polynomials in $R[X]$. I am having problems extending the argument to $k[X]$.

Comment: Can you extend it to the field of fractions of $R[X]$?

Comment: We can make do with a smaller extension than the field of fractions: $k[X]$ is $R[X]$ with nonzero elements in $R$ inverted; so a polynomial in $k[X]$ may be written as $f/a$ for $f \in R[X]$ and $a \in R$. Can you do it then?

Comment: Bernard your comment is interesting. The quotient ring of $R[X]$ is the field of rational functions in a single variable, which contains the ring $k[X]$. So if we can prove that the identity holds in the field of rational functions, it should automatically hold in $k[X]$. Am thinking…!Thanks.

Comment: Joshua, that is how I worked in my argument below

Answer (score 1):

In $k$ we can check that for any particular prime $p\in{R}$, and for $(x, y)\in{k\times{k}},$ ${{\nu}_p}(xy) = {{\nu}_p}(x){{\nu}_p}(y)$ using unique factorization in $k$ (the exponents can be any integer, positive, zero or negative-we factor the numerator and denominator separately an simplify). Next we can check that for $a\in{k},$ and $f(X)\in{k[X]},$ $${{\nu}_p}(af(X))={{\nu}_p}(a)+{{\nu}_p}(f(X)).$$ Finally, if $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are both non-constant polynomials in $k[X]$, we can clear fractions by multiplying each polynomial by the least common multiple of the denominators of all coefficients, and then use the above facts to prove the general case.
Is there a more elegant proof? This proof works but is tedious.